# Lazy Loading NSTableView MAC OS X

Tags: cocoa, lazy-loading, nstableview

I wants to implement lazy loading in my `NSTableView`, I am displaying image from url so My `NSTableView` not scrolling well. I am googling from last few hours. there are many tutorial for `UITableView` but not for `NSTableView` MAC OS X. can any one help me.

I am using following code.

```
-(NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{

// Get a new ViewCell
NSTableCellView *cellView = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];


NSString *identifier=[tableColumn identifier];
NSLog(@"identifier is %@",identifier);

if( [tableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:@"MainCell"] ){

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[artUrl objectAtIndex:row]];
NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

cellView.imageView.image = image;
cellView.textField.stringValue = [stationName objectAtIndex:row];
return cellView;

}
```

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "lazy loading" your table view?